# How does laravel load config files

Tags: php, laravel, config

All laravel configuration files are found inside the `config` directory and all of them are returned as an associative array

```
//for example Session.php
return[

   /******************************
   * session name
   ******************************/
   "name" => "newBlog"
];
```

Later on this configuration can be used like this

```
Config::get("session.name");
```

How does this method `get` works ?? is it using `require` to require all these files ??? i tried to find the file of the config class but i didn't get the logic 
`Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config` i cant find the get method

so please how is this implemented ??? what's the logic behind?

Comment: Mine is implemented in `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Config/Repository.php` if you want to look there for the code.

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/how-laravel-facades-work-and-how-to-use-them-elsewhere/

Comment: Yeah i can find the `get` method there which is by itself using another class `Arr::get()` which can be found on the support folder in the same dir but i can get the logic how these config files are loaded ??

Comment: Are you having a problem you're trying to fix, or just curious?

Answer (score 4):

This is what a laravel config file looks like:

```
// /tmp/file1.php                                                           
<?php                                                                        
return [                                                                     
    'answer' => 42,                                                                
];
```

The following logic is used to load the file and store the value into a variable ([see in laravel](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/LoadConfiguration.php#L71)):

```
$a = require '/tmp/file1.php'                                                 
var_dump($a);
```

In Laravel the value is stored in a class called [Repository](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Config/Repository.php)

Comment: I don't know why it was so hard to find this answer! I was just looking for how to read in a php file as an object! thank you

Answer (score 3):

It is in `Illuminate\Config\Repository`

```
public function get($key, $default = null)
{
    return Arr::get($this->items, $key, $default);
}
```

Further, instead of Config facade, you can use config helper as `config('session.name')`

Comment: and how the `Arr::get()` is loading these files ! i have already seen all these files i wan to get the logic

Comment: This happens at the bootstrapping of the application. Basically when bootstrapping, all the config values are set in the Config repository's $item variable. See `Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap > LoadConfiguration.php`  `function bootstrap()`

Answer (score 2):

The `\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\LoadConfiguration::getConfigurationFiles` method returns an array of config values parsed from .php files found in `/config/*.php` and the order in which they are parsed is due to the SORT_NATURAL flag (`ksort($files, SORT_NATURAL);`), so [natural alphabetical/numerical ordering](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php) on the php file names. `getConfigurationFiles()` is not invoked however if config is loaded from cache.